# Android JavaScript Interface with asp.net

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net

I am developing an android application. I need to call an android function from the web view. I found a code from internet that calls android toast message from a HTML page using JavaScript. That code works correctly with an HTML page but not working when i use an asp.net web form. Here i share that code with you. Please tell me how can i implement this process using an asp.net web form. Thanks in advance

Code of Android Activity :

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/mypage.html");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this),  "app");
}   
public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface{
    private Context context;       
    public WebViewJavaScriptInterface(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }        
    @JavascriptInterface
  public void makeToast(String message, boolean lengthLong){                 
        Toast.makeText(context, message, (lengthLong ? Toast.LENGTH_LONG : Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)).show();
    }
}
    }
```

Layout of Activity :

```
    <RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

HTML Page :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>JavaScript View</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showToast(){
        var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
        var lengthLong = document.getElementById("length").checked;            
        app.makeToast(message, lengthLong);
        return false;
    }        
    window.onload = function(){
        var form = document.getElementById("form");
        form.onsubmit = showToast;
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form">
    Message: <input id="message" name="message" type="text"/><br />
    Long: <input id="length" name="length" type="checkbox" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Make Toast" />
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your HTML page assets folder or raw folder as drawable is meant to images resources.

And make sure you load URL in webview at the end after setting JavaScript bridge.

Comment: The code works correctly with an html page but i need to implement this process in asp.net. I tried the above java script in my asp.net web form but it is not working. any suggestion?

Comment: Try once by adding load ur at the end. Asp.net or php or anything it doesn't matter I guess. Try adding logs n break points check whether your method are getting called or not

Comment: Did u found the issue ?

Comment: I tried adding load url at the end and then it is working perfectly. Thank You So Much Suresh

Comment: Sushant here Not Suresh

Comment: Missed up voting the ans